# Enable @devs to create wild repos, read/write their own master but not push to other's dev master

Tags: gitolite

What I am trying to achieve is, that `@dev` group can make their own repos, do whatever on their `dev/` branches, but can only push to their own repo `master` branch, and read only others developers `master` branches.

I have setup my rules like this in `gitolite.conf`:

```
@projects = projects/..*  


repo @projects
    C           = @devs
    - master$   = @devs
    RW+ master$ = CREATOR
    RW+         = @admin TRUSTED
    RW+ dev/    = @devs
    RW          = @devs
```

When I check for access for a particular dev, that I would like him to be able to READ `master`, result is DENIED?

```
gitolite access -s projects/a1 [dev-member] R master

legend:
    d => skipped deny rule due to ref unknown or 'any',
    r => skipped due to refex not matching,
    p => skipped due to perm (W, +, etc) not matching,
    D => explicitly denied,
    A => explicitly allowed,
    F => denied due to fallthru (no rules matched)

  p        gitolite.conf:37         C           = @devs
  D        gitolite.conf:39         -   master$ = @devs

R refs/heads/master projects/a1 [dev-member] DENIED by refs/heads/master$
```

Same happens for me as the CREATOR of this repo, so I am not able even to READ my own `master` branch. How would I resolve this?

Even more confusing is the following case:

Given the fact that `branquito` is in `@admin` group.

```
gitolite access -s projects/a1 branquito W master
legend:
    ...

  p        gitolite.conf:37         C           = @devs
  D        gitolite.conf:38             -   master$ = @devs

W refs/heads/master projects/a1 branquito DENIED by refs/heads/master$
```

but:

```
gitolite access -s projects/a1 @admin W master
legend:
    ...

  A        gitolite.conf:40         RW+         = @admin TRUSTED

refs/.*
```